# Update other view based on selection of first view?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I want to update profile based on click from data ul.

How to do it?

html :

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="cont">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in data">{{val.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="profile-ul">
            <li>profile should repeat here</li>
        </ul>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS :

```
var data = [{ 
    'name' : 'A',
    'profile' : ['A 1','A 2','A 3']
},
{ 
    'name' : 'B',
    'profile' : ['B 1','B 2','B 3']
}
]
var angApp = angular.module('test',[]);
angApp.controller('cont', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.data = data;
}])
```

Here [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gautm5154/b57yenzp/3/) to work with.

Comment: Use ng-view in html swith your viewshelp of $routeProvider .check the link hope help for your requirement https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: If you want to store variables/data to use in other parts of your application, or maybe you want to use them global, you can store them into $rootScope instead of $scope. $rootScope is available across all controllers/views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my self :

html :

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="cont">
        <ul>
            <li ng-click="updateKey(val)" ng-repeat="(key, val) in data">{{val.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="profile-ul">
            <li ng-repeat="val in profile">{{val}}</li>
        </ul>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS :

```
var data = [{ 
    'name' : 'A',
    'profile' : ['A 1','A 2','A 3']
},
{ 
    'name' : 'B',
    'profile' : ['B 1','B 2','B 3']
}
]
var angApp = angular.module('test',[]);
angApp.controller('cont', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.updateKey = function(data){
        $scope.profile = data.profile;
    }
}])
```

here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gautm5154/b57yenzp/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/hh5kwf4n/

```
var data = [{ 
    'name' : 'A',
    'profile' : ['A 1','A 2','A 3']
},
{ 
    'name' : 'B',
    'profile' : ['B 1','B 2','B 3']
}
]
var angApp = angular.module('test',[]);
angApp.controller('cont', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.profile = ['A','B','C'];    

    $scope.updateProfile = function(key) {
        $scope.selectedProfile = data[key];
    };
}])
```

and the HTML

```
<div ng-app="test">
    <div ng-controller="cont">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in data" ng-click="updateProfile(key)">{{val.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="profile-ul">
            <li ng-repeat="item in selectedProfile.profile">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

Explanation: by putting `{{selectedProfile.name}}` in our view, we're telling the view to replace that with whatever is the value of given variable, which is our "model"

Next...by adding `ng-click="updateProfile(key)"` to a li tag, we're making sure that each time a li tag is clicked, `updateProfile` function will be called, and the key of current element will be passed to it.

And finally, in our controller, we have the function `updateProfile` which based on key passed to it, updates the value of our model - `selectedProfile`.

Now...as soon as model is updated, the view gets automatically updated, and that's it:)

Comment: I want to loop through selected data.profile and display them.

Comment: Edited, now it also loops through data.profile of selected item.

Comment: I also figured out. :)